# Ошибка в клавиатуре

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Когда я пытаюсь влепить 3 кнопки в строку а кнопку "Назад" столбиком вылетает ошибка

```
import vk_api
import time
import random
import json
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotEventType, VkBotLongPoll

token = "token"

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

vk._auth_token()

keyboardmenu2 = {
    "one_time": False,
    "buttons": [
        [{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"1\"}",
                "label": "Нищий"
            },
            "color": "positive"
        },
            {
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                    "label": "Обычный"
                },
                "color": "positive"
        },
            {
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                    "label": "Богатый"
                },
                "color": "positive"
        }, [{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"4\"}",
                "label": "Назад"
            },
            "color": "secondary"
        }],
        ]
    ]
}

keyboardmenu2 = json.dumps(keyboardmenu2, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
keyboardmenu2 = str(keyboardmenu2.decode('utf-8'))

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, id)

menutext = "Если ты здесь первый раз прочитай описание"

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.object.text.lower() == "старт":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id, "message": str(menutext), "random_id": 0, "keyboard": keyboardmenu})
            if event.object.text.lower() == "играть":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,"message": "Выберете один из режимов", "random_id": 0, "keyboard": keyboardmenu2})
            if event.object.text.lower() == "описание":
                message("Прочитать описание ты можешь тут \n https://vk.com/link")
            if event.object.text.lower() == "назад":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id, "message": str(menutext), "random_id": 0, "keyboard": keyboardmenu})
```

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [911] Keyboard format is invalid: button [0][3] has invalid action

Ошибка

Answer (score 0):

У тебе стоит `keyboardmenu2`, а на кнопке `'старт'` и `'назад'` стоит `keyboardmenu`